# Why am I receiving a 401 Unauthorized error when requesting API data from React?

Tags: reactjs, express, server-side-rendering

To make a long story short, I'm building a server-rendered Express / React application and I'm trying to query the back-end, from the client, for some data. The basic flow looks like this:

1. User navigates to a client path `applications/:id`
2. The `Application` component is loaded
3. A `GET` request is made to the server's API from the `Application` component lifecycle method `componentWillMount`
4. The data from the response is added to Redux

The problem is that the response (step 4) is a 401 (Unauthorized). This is not an issue of being logged in or not. A valid session exists and if I navigate to the API route from the browser, I can see the expected response. As an added note, this application is similar to another application (in nearly ever relevant aspect), which does not have this issue.

Attempted troubleshooting steps:

1. Verified correct modules and versions
2. Verified correct API request path and configuration (using Axios and `withCredentials` config param)
3. Verified server routing and authentication
4. Verified PassportJS config
5. Verified the request session is being lost in the auth process

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the problem was that I was making the API request from the `componentWillMount` React lifecycle method. In other words, since the component in question was being rendered on the server and wasn't yet complete, the API call was being made from the server side as well (the component had not yet mounted), meaning the cookie was not available for the API request. Hence the 401 Unauthorized error.

Reading [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount) first would have saved me quite a bit of trouble:

> componentWillMount() ...
>
> Avoid introducing any side-effects or subscriptions in this method. For those use cases, use componentDidMount() instead.
>
> This is the only lifecycle hook called on server rendering.